# Prevent hidden textbox postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make MVC ignore posting a bound textbox if it is currently hidden?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { style = "display:none;"})
```

I dont really want to use javascript to accomplish this but wanted to know if it was possible with MVC out of the box.

Here is a javascript solution: 
Clear ID and Name field of any hidden textbox before post to prevent MVC from binding.

Is there a better non javascript way to get to the same end game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make it disabled:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { style = "display:none;", disabled = "disabled"})
```

Comment: This will definitely work, but as a question to the OP: why would you even need a disabled and hidden text box rendered? The user can't see it and it effectively does nothing, so you might as well just not even have it.

Comment: And Boom goes the dynamite!! Thanks!! So simple.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The input isnt always disabled, it will show when a user presses a button. Now i can show the input and remove the disabled attr.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I do not know the entire need of it, but if you want to bring some data from back-end, and need to persist this data on html code (to work with it on front-end, for example) and you do not need to post back it to server again, I will sugest to avoid TextBoxFor and persist is as 'data-' attribute.

```
<div id="someId" data-my-important-value="@Model.Value"> ... </div>
```

Like this, you will bring your data from your back-end, will ensure that this will be not posted back do server again, and will be able to request it from front-end using javascript, jQuery, angujarJs...

```
var importantValue = $('#someId').attr('data-my-important-value');
```

As I said, just another wait to threat the scenario. As @MajoB already gave a quick and workfull answer.